# pandas series get value by index's value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a question about Pandas series. I have a series as following:

[image]

The data type is:

[image]

And would like to get the instance that HSHLD_ID = 2000000040054, but not sure how to do that.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `df.loc[2000000040054]`?

Comment: @QuangHoang. Key error. Thanks.

Comment: 1) Check data type of the index, is it string or is it integer? 2) Key error can be your key is not in the index.

Comment: Not sure why, but the only answer works. We need additional []. Do you know why?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why. You data is double index, so `hh_data.loc[2000000040054]` should work equivalently to that answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, single [] won't work, only double [] works. I think it is due to the dataframe

Answer (score 1):

if i got it right, then i think: `hh_data.loc[[2000000040054]]` should be your sulotion

Comment: Awesome! That is the correct answer. Would you mind explaining more here? Thanks.